Change detection in Angular for timers
I was going through the Angular source code trying to find out how change detection is triggered for timers.
I know they are patched, but I can't find a place where the actual change detection is triggered for timers.
Does anyone know? Can you please share the source code links?

In zone-based apps, zone.js patches (among others), setTimeout and setInterval. This means any function that is based on them (like the timer operator from rxjs), will schedule change detection.
All patched APIs will contribute to the microtaskQueue maintained by zone.js.
Angular listens to this queue, and when it's empty, it fires a change detection :
this._onMicrotaskEmptySubscription = this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
  next: () => {
    // `onMicroTaskEmpty` can happen _during_ the zoneless scheduler change detection because
    // zone.run(() => {}) will result in `checkStable` at the end of the `zone.run` closure
    // and emit `onMicrotaskEmpty` synchronously if run coalsecing is false.
    if (this.changeDetectionScheduler?.runningTick) {
      return;
    }
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.applicationRef.tick();
    });
  }
});

Source code for v18
